# Selected database data from static dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, html

So i have this:

```
<select name="study_year">
<option>Year I</option>
<option>Year II</option>
<option>Year III</option>
</select>
```

I have an option already set in the database from the INSERT when i added the user but now i want to edit.php it and how do i select by default the value from database

I'm using this fetch array to get the value from the db but i dont know how to apply it in the selected="" attribute:

```
$list_study=(mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT study_year from study WHERE $ID_stud=study.ID_stud")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic but ugly way to do this is:

```
<select name="study_year">
<option <?php echo $selected['Year I'];?>>Year I</option>
<option<?php echo $selected['Year II'];?>>Year II</option>
<option<?php echo $selected['Year III'];?>>Year III</option>
</select>
```

and

```
<?php
$selected=array('Year I'=>'','Year II'=>'','Year III'=>'');
//Query year into $year
$selected[$year]='selected';
?>
```

Comment: I cant get it to work...By query you mean the thing i wrote in the main post? The result of that query is for ID_stud=20 for example "Year I"

Comment: What your wrote is an acceptable start. You still need to get the year from the row and put it into $year

Comment: I figured it out but i did it somewhat different, thx for the tips

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the "$list_study" query returns a single value something like "Year I"
you can add this condition on all options in the select

```
<?php if($list_study == "Year I"){echo"selected";}?>
```

For Example:

```
<select name="study_year">
<option <?php if($list_study == "Year I"){echo"selected";}?> >Year I</option>
<option <?php if($list_study == "Year II"){echo"selected";}?> >Year II</option>
<option <?php if($list_study == "Year III"){echo"selected";}?> >Year III</option>
</select>
```